# Require() and import don't seem to work the same way

Tags: javascript, json, frontend

For webdev context I want my index.js to import index.json.

When I make use of require() I receive the JSON on my VSCode debug console, but on my browser I get the error **ReferenceError: require is not defined**

```
try {
    const dataJson = require('./index.json');
    console.log(dataJson[0]);
} catch(e) {
    console.log(e);
}
```

But when I use import, I receive the JSON on my browser, but my VSCode console returns an exception **Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module**

```
import jsonImport from './index.json' assert {type: 'json'};
console.log(jsonImport[0]);
```

Can I get some leads on how to properly import JSON to my .js files?

Comment: either mark the project as `"type": "module"` or name your file `whatever.mjs` instead of `whatever.js`